# bootstrap accordion - don't collapse if clicking on open panel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up bootstrap to hide currently open panels when opening a new panel using:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

I would like to extend this so that nothing happens if you click on a currently open panel, i.e. the open panel should stay open when clicking on it. It should only collapse when clicking on other collapsed panels.

I tried it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  $('.in').not(this).collapse('hide');
});
```

Is this possible somehow?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r66L5851/)

Comment: Can you post a complete working example? HTML too.

Comment: I edited my initial post and added a link to a working example on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap adds the class 'in' to open panels, you can use that to detect weather the panel is already open, if so then you can skip the collapsing by invoking a `event.stopPropagation()` you can read more about stopPropagation [here](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

```
$('.panel-title > a[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(e){
  target = $(this).attr('href')
  if ($(target).hasClass('in')) {
    e.preventDefault(); // to stop the page jump to the anchor target.
    e.stopPropagation()
  }
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r66L5851/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work either. I added a link to JSFiddle in my initial post so you can have a look at it.

Comment: adding the JSFiddle was helpful. Revised answer

Comment: Thanks! Your example works, but e.stopPropagation() caused the browser to jump to the target element on the site I'm working on. I fixed it by changing e.stopPropagation() to return false;.

Comment: you can add e.preventDefault(); as well to avoid that. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

According to @Sammy answer - for the Bootstrap 4.x you have to change

```
    if ($(target).hasClass('in'))
```

to

```
    if ($(target).hasClass('show'))
```